# quantize a grayscale image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, quantization

I've read a text image, converted it to a grayscale image and applied sobel operator. Now I want to "quantize the image".

Comment: Why do you want to do something you have no clue about ?  The way to become 'not-a-newbie' is to put in some work and figure a few things out.  What have you done already, what particular issues are you stuck on ?

Comment: Would be better on [Signal processing stack](http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm actually trying to implement an algorithm which was designed in my university...  As of now, I have written a algorithm to detect every line in the image from the first col to the last col and smilarly the first row to the last row ...Calculate few conditions in each line and then shift only few characters...
Now the algorithm says " Apply edge detection and Quantize".
I did the edge detection part, Now i'm stuck with the "Quantize" part

Answer (score 4):

Convert the uint8 image to double and divide by 255. Multiply by amount of quanta you want, say 50, and convert it back to uint8. Now you have quantized it. To view it properly, convert it to double again and divide by 50, use imshow. Sample code:

```
img = imread("image.jpg");
quanta = 50;
img = double(img) / 255;
img = uint8(img * quanta);
img = double(img) / quanta;
```

Answer (score 0):

image quantization

```
clear

new = [0.3 0.5 0.05;1 0.1 0.03;0.01 0.4 0.02;0.23 0.7 0.8];

new1=zeros(3,3);

for i=1:3

    for j=1:3
         if new(i,j)<1
              new1(i,j)=new(i,j)*256;
         else
              new1(i,j)=new(i,j);
         end
    end
end
new
new1
```

Comment: @BradLarson - thank you for paying attention to this flaged answer. However, in what way do you think your edit made it better? it is cryptic and unclear. More importantly, it has little explanation on how it addresses the question. This is NOT a reasonable-quality answer

Comment: @Shai - It is code, and is an attempt at an answer. In a case like this, I give the benefit of the doubt to the answerer. I do not feel comfortable deleting an honest effort at an answer, even if it is wrong, and would like to give them a chance to clarify what they've posted.

Comment: @BradLarson I agree that we should encourage new users, but at the what cost? Quoting from ["The war of closes" blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/?cb=1): "We can’t lower our standards. We won’t."